# cookbook ignores platform specified in metadata.rb

Tags: chef-infra, cookbook

I am facing an issue where a cookbook designed only for the Windows platform is being picked up by Linux nodes during regular Chef runs, resulting in failures.

Cookbook doesn't have any dependencies that could conflict.

`supports 'windows'` is specified in `metadata.rb` and the server picks up accordingly but not sure why Linux nodes are being targeted.

While I could add a logic to ignore Linux nodes, I believe that the metadata support should be read before the node attempts to compile the recipe.
Has anyone else encountered this problem?

The client version is 14